# Compile only modified files with nmake

Tags: compiler-construction, nmake

I am trying to modify this big program which takes almost 10 minutes to compile using nmake.

Now if I modify one or few of the .cpp files, nmake is smart enough to compile just those that are changed and not the rest of the project. But if I modify the header files I have to compile the whole thing again. Is there anyway to avoid that?

Comment: I want to avoid that because I have to modify things all the time and takes forever until it's compiled. It's a commercial package and I am not getting any errors.

Answer (score 3):

Nmake is right in recompiling everything that depends on a header. Only a decent compiler or parser of the language you chose is able to judge if any data layouts changed.

If Nmake would not do this, the probability is high that you soon would step into the world of segfault and bus errors.

The proper way around is to organise your headers more cleanly and only include what you need.

Comment: So if I've got sample.h and sample.cpp and I modify the header file nmake doesn't notice it, right? what if I make a dummy change to the sample.cpp as well? maybe that works, I have to try it

Comment: I thought nmake is smart enough to also recompile sample.cpp in case you tweak the header?

Comment: Btw, there is a lot of advice if you look for "organising source code" and similar. If you often have to change headers, there exist cures, one of them being the pimpl idiom.